# Por que alguns campos e métodos em JavaScript podem ser declarados com '#'?

Tags: javascript, private

Estava estudando um código JavaScript e me deparei com a sintaxe abaixo:

```
export class MyClass {
  #msg;
  #anyThing;
  #logTypes;

  constructor(...) {
   // todo
  }

  #myMethod() {
   // todo
  }

}
```

Qual a função do símbolo `#`?

Answer (score 5):

Esta é a sintaxe para declarar [campos e métodos privados](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).

Atualmente a [proposta que define esta sintaxe](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) está em [Estágio 3](https://tc39.es/process-document/) ("*further refinement will require feedback from implementations and users*"), mas [já possui um bom suporte dos browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility).

Um pequeno exemplo:

```js
class Exemplo {
    #campoPrivado;

    constructor(v1, v2) {
        this.#campoPrivado = v1;
        this.campoPublico = v2;
    }

    #metodoPrivado() {
        console.log('método privado: ', this.#campoPrivado);
    }

    metodoPublico() {
        console.log('método público chamando o método privado:');
        this.#metodoPrivado();
    }
}

var x = new Exemplo(1, 2);
console.log(x.campoPublico); // 2

// descomente a linha abaixo, que dará erro
// console.log(x.#campoPrivado); // ERRO!

x.metodoPublico(); // funciona normalmente

// descomente as linhas abaixo, que dará erro
// x.#metodoPrivado();
// x.metodoPrivado();
```

Repare que o campo e o método privado só podem ser acessados dentro da própria classe. Ao tentar acessá-los de fora, dá erro.

---

Veja a definição completa na [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-class-definitions). E mais alguns exemplos na já referida [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).